# How to remove #more... from the post "More" link?

Tags: read-more

When you insert the "More" link into a post using the "Insert More Break" toolbar icon, the url that is generated is appended with "#more-".  Thus when you click that link, you get the full post (via single.php), but the browser then scrolls to where the 'more' was inserted.

Is there a filter I can use to remove the "#more-"?

What I want is to *not* scroll to the 'more' link when the full post is displayed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go this will prevent scroll (add to functions.php)

```
function remove_more_link_scroll( $link ) {
$link = preg_replace( '|#more-[0-9]+|', '', $link );
return $link;
}
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'remove_more_link_scroll' );
```

Explained in depth [Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Prevent_Page_Scroll_When_Clicking_the_More_Link).

Comment: Excellent - thanks Dejo Dekic - just what the doctor ordered.

Comment: Cool glad to help:)

Answer (score 1):

I know a rather simple way to achieve that, with just one line of code.

```
the_content( '' );
```

Note that you have to use it in the templates responsible for displaying the content at appropriate places, and not in `functions.php`. I bet you won't see that #more... link again.